# How to know the azure role assignment already exists

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to get the current role assignment status.

e.g : I assigned contributer role to my web app

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId 43fddad0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-665033f5fbf0 -RoleDefinitionName "Storage Blob Data Contributor" -Scope "/subscriptions/4364666b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-47158904c439/resourceGroups/devt002RG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/devt002"
```

When i run the above command in VSTS again it will give error message

```
2019-04-02T10:22:58.2614183Z ##[error]The role assignment already exists.
```

I just want to get the current status of role (Storage Blob Data Contributor) assignment to my web app, if it is already exist i will skip the assignment.

I tried :

```
Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -Scope "/subscriptions/4364666b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-47158904c439/resourceGroups/devt002RG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/devt002"
Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -Id 43fddad0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-665033f5fbf0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you are using the right command, you just need to build some logic around it to be able to determine if the assignment already exists.

If you know the GUID beforehand:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId "GUID"
```

Is the easiest way to check

Comment: yes, i'm using the new notation because the old one is depreciated

Comment: Its output is : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.Models.Authorization.PSRoleAssignment

How can i know it has 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role assigned if my web app has more than one role.

Comment: ok got it. 
$check = Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId "43fddad0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-665033f5fbf0"
write-host "Assign role name :" $check.RoleDefinitionName